# .htaccess redirect query string value to another key

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

What i'm trying to do is rewrite the following pattern

> `http://example.org/path?articleid=5657`

to this pattern:

> `http://example.org/path?p=5657`

Essentially it comes down to changing the key to the url parameter, i have searched extensively with no clear example of how to do this exact thing using only htaccess rewrite rules.

i've tried this general approach with no luck

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^articleid=([0-9]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^articleid=([0-9]*)$ /?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in the pattern of a rule, you need to match against the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^articleid=([0-9]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^path$ /path?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```