# .htaccess - Very specific redirecting?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried wrapping my head around this and it seems I cannot - My basic need to provide redirecting for users on my site that may have bookmarks to older locations. Example:

www.example.com/users/userprofile=122&action=edit

Needs to be:

www.example.com/users/id=122&action=edit

---

I've tried a variety of methods and rewrite rules, and I can't seem to come up with a solution.

Note that the ***action*** can be a variety of things - And may sometimes feature other extensions afterwards for instance:

www.example.com/users/userprofile=122&action=edit&theme=blue

Note that the use of '/users' is a rewrite rule of it's own - The real directory is "assets".

I won't bother posting what I've tried - Just half a dozen "**500 Internal Server errors**".

Comment: you can't rewrite a query string (i guess you forgot the ?) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281229/htaccess-redirect-query-string-value-to-another-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(users)/userprofile=(.+)$ /$1/id=$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```